# React call stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i am trying to get some data from the backend just before my `home` component renders:

This is the `home` component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //asta e o alternativa la componentwillmount dar nu pot sa alterez
    //starea in constructor cica
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('componentWillMount is executing')
    console.log(store.getState())
    //GetInitialData.bind(this)()
    GetInitialData();
    console.log('component should have executed')
  }
```

This is my stateless component responsible for making the request and dispatching the response to the redux store:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { get_library } from '../../Redux/actions/Actions' 
import store from "../../Redux/store/Store";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    get_library : context => dispatch(get_library(context))
  }
}

const GetInitialData2 = () => {
  console.log('This should work')
}

const GetInitialData = (props) => {

  console.log('Making the GET request')
  //axios.get('http://localhost:8080/try')
  axios({
    method : 'get',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/getLibrary',
    headers : {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + getToken(),
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Store in Initial Data')
    console.log(store.getState())
    //store.dispatch(get_library(response.data))
    //this.props.store.dispatch(get_library(response.data))
    props.get_library(response.data)
    //this.setState({ data: response.data });
    console.log('New state now')
    //console.log(this.state)
  })
};

function getToken() {
    // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
    return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    }


//function GetInitialData (){ connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Connected_GetInitialData)}

//export default GetInitialData;
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(GetInitialData)

export default GetInitialData2;
```

My problem is that i keep getting `props is not defined` error which is pointing to the `home` component, no matter what. Even if i call GetInitialData2(which only prints something) or GetInitialData.

There is something i'm not understanding. I don't need to pass anything to my GetInitialData function since all it does is alter the redux store.

> EDIT - With middleware:

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('In DidMount, calling function');
    GetInitialData();
    console.log('DidMount should have executed');
  }
```

And:

```
const GetInitialData = () => {

  console.log('Making the GET request')
  //axios.get('http://localhost:8080/try')
  axios({
    method : 'get',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/getLibrary',
    headers : {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + getToken(),
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Store in Initial Data')
    console.log(store.getState())
    console.log(response.data)
    //store.dispatch(get_library(response.data))
    store.dispatch(get_library(response.data))
    //this.setState({ data: response.data });
    console.log('New store state now')
    console.log(store.getState())
  })
};

function getToken() {
    // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
    return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    }


export default GetInitialData;
```

The result is that it just stops at `store.dispatch` and does nothing. All the `console.logs` work and i get a valid response.

> Result... after too many hours: Seems that it was failing silently at
>   reducer level where i had:

```
const initialState = {
  library: {},
  playlist_names: [],
  playlists : [],
  songs : [],
  articles : [],
};
```

And instead it should have been : `library : [];`, the error was: `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`. I only got to this by printing the `response.data` in the console and manually running `store.dispatch` from browser console... I still do not understand why that error didn't surface.

Comment: I would suggest to use a middleware for these kind of things. In middleware, you can access the state and dispatch as well. You would only need to dispatch an action in componentDidMount() and listen to that action in the middleware.

Comment: @kuby Thx, i was doing this even if i didn't know it was called like this, in fact is using `store.dispatch(action_name(context))` or something similar. I'm having difficulties with this line not producing any effect tho...

Comment: So what you would need to do is: 1. dispatch an action, example: 'MY_ACTION', 2. in the middleware, make an if statement to this action, 3. if it hits, call the axios or whatever you are using to fetch the data, 4. on successfull fetch, dispatch an action with your data from API response.

Comment: @kuby i updated the question with the middleware i'm trying to use.

Comment: But that is not a redux middleware. A redux middleware must be registered to your store in order to check for actions. You can read about how to use it here: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware

Comment: @kuby Thx for ur help, what i wrote seems to me very much like `Attempt 1` in the link you provided. I might be very wrong. I'll read again.